# Python OpenCV2: Ordering contours and tree hierarchy by contour area

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to iterate through a list of contours by their area (highest area to lowest).

I know one way to do this is by using:

```
_, contours, heirachy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for contour in sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True):
    ...
```

However, what I also want to do is access the hierarchical relationship between the contours while iterating - at best I would like to see how many contours are contained within each outer parents contour, however I would also be happy simply finding outer contours that are parents to inner contours.

```
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i in zip(contours, hierarchy):
    contour = i[0]
    relations = i[1]
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

    # outer contours:
    if relations[3] < 0:
        # checks if it is squarish
        if 0.85 < (w / h) < 1.1:
            corner += 1

    if corner == 3:
        break
```

What I am struggling with is being able to zip the contours together so they can both be accessed simultabeously, but also iterate through them from highest to lowest area as done above.

Note that the purpose of this is to find the three marked corners of a QR code, so I want to be able to find the outer contours and also iterate from highest area to lowest area in order to ensure the contours found first are the large corner squares and not the smaller squares within the QR code

Comment: Some kind of indirect sort, perhaps?

Comment: @DanMašek How would you suggest going about that?

Comment: Something along the lines of `indices = sorted( range(len(contours)), key=lambda i : cv2.contourArea(contours[i]) )`